# How to change name using RegEx and Preg_replace?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, preg-replace

The DisplayRow function in this online examples used in the regular expression examples take a line of input from my data file and displays the HTML for one row of the resulting table.

I would like to modify the function so that I can display the names as an email link so that it looks like userid@ccsf.edu, where the name “Thomas, Boegel” will be tboegel.

**My Question**: What is wrong with my regex pattern in preg_replace and why doesn't the names update.

I have some code which shows names in an array inside of the variable $parts at the far right of a table. Here is the code I need to change:

```
for ($i = 10; $i < count($parts); $i += 1) { 
    print preg_replace('/^([a-z]+), ([a-z])[a-z]*/i','<a href="mailto:$2$1@ccsf.edu">/a>', $parts[$i]);
}
```

Here is the entire function. I only need help with the chunk of code above. There are only a few names and they are all in the same format jole, billy and I am trying to change it to jbilly inside of an email link.

```
function DisplayRow($target) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    $parts = split(" +", $target);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i+=1) {
      print "<td>$parts[$i]</td>\n";
    }
    print "<td>\n";
    for ($i = 10; $i < count($parts); $i += 1) {
        print preg_replace('/([a-z]+), ([a-z])[a-z]*/i', '<a href="mailto:$2$1@ccsf.edu"> </a>', $parts[$i]);
}
```

Comment: This code works, but when I add the preg_replace() to my function to modify the names in $parts[$i] inside the loop above, nothing changes.                                                        $name = 'billy, jole';
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+, [a-z]+/i', $name, $yes)) {
print preg_replace('/^([a-z]+), ([a-z])[a-z]*/i','<a href="mailto:$2$1@ccsf.edu"></a>', $name);

Comment: Could you show us what the print outputs in the first loop?

Comment: I can't post images because my reputation is to low.

Comment: We don't need images, we need data that fails with your regex to test.

Comment: Then names looking originally like this: Common, Kurt and       Hanada, Violet S. However my results look like this: Common,Kurt and Hanada,VioletS. What I want is for my output to like:           <a href=/"mailto:KCommon@ccsf.edu/">KCommon@ccsf.edu</a>          <a href=/"mailto:VHanada@ccsf.edu/">VHanada@ccsf.edu</a>

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `$2$1` inside the `<a>` tag.

```
preg_replace('/\b([a-z]+), ([a-z])[a-z]*/i', '<a href="mailto:$2$1@ccsf.edu">$2$1@ccsf.edu</a>', $parts[$i]);
```